# How to center a specific caption?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I'm having a problem with centering my figure captions. Particuarly, I know that we can use `\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}` to center captions, however, I'm interested in just centering a specific caption. I've read the caption manual but no luck, so my question is: How can I center a specific caption?

Comment: You can use `\captionsetup{justification=centering}` in the specific `table` or `figure` environment (after `\usepackage{caption}`.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, it worked! Please add as an aswer so I can close the question. :)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can use `\captionsetup` in a specific `figure` (or `table`) environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering

\includegraphics[scale=.30]{example-image-a}

\caption{A caption with long text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\includegraphics[scale=.30]{example-image-b}

\caption{A caption with long text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}

\includegraphics[scale=.30]{example-image-c}

\caption{A caption with long text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this also work for subfigures?

Comment: @ShuvoSarker I don't know, why don't you try?

Comment: @ShuvoSarker It does not, they just jump all the way to the right! Very annoying...

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? It's really hard to understand why an answer that does, with minimal intervention, exactly what the OP asked gets downvoted.