# How to center a caption inside a minipage?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

In this moment I have something like that

[image]

and I want this

[image]

and this is the portion of the code

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \subsection{Tercera Configuraci\'on}
    Con ayuda de un gancho conductor tipo cocodrilo, conectar los polos positivo y negativo, en una misma linea de conducci\'on pero en diferentes nodos. (Ver Figura 4)
\vspace{1.3cm}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.53\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.14]{CuboTres.png}
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \captionof{figure}{Tercer montaje}
\end{minipage}
```

I saw this similar question " [How to center a specific caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95207/how-to-center-a-specific-caption) " but in my case doesn't work.

I'm using MiKTeX and TeXworks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: I replaced your image with example-image (from the mwe package) and it worked fine.  I even put a \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt} above it to check the alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A \centering inside the minipage should do the trick, working on my side.

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
\subsection{Tercera Configuraci\'on}
Con ...
\vspace{1.3cm}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.53\linewidth}
\centering
   \includegraphics[scale=0.14]{CuboTres.png}
   \captionsetup{justification=centering}
   \captionof{figure}{Tercer montaje}
\end{minipage}
```

regards

Comment: thanks but i don't want to move the image too, i just want to move the captions

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's sometimes better to provide complete examples instead of fragments of code only

Comment: @OmarRodriguez just move the `\centering` down after a blank line after the `\includeimage` (but it's more normal to centre both if you are centering the caption)